# globals() function having weird behaviours in python

Tags: python, global

I've been bugged by the python function `globals()`, and I have no idea what is happening.

```
def foo():
    if False:
        x = 2
    elif True:
        globals()['x'] = 2
        print(x)
        
def foo2():
    if False:
        y = 2
    elif True:
        globals()['x'] = 2
        print(x)

foo2()
print("foo2 function working well")
foo()
```

This gives me the following results :

```
2 
foo2 function working well!

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-4e0c45e0bd37> in <module>
     14 
     15 foo2()
---> 16 foo()

<ipython-input-66-4e0c45e0bd37> in foo()
      4     elif True:
      5         globals()['x'] = 2
----> 6         print(x, "Working well!")
      7 
      8 def foo2():

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

So basically, having `x` defined in the condition before, even if not used, will generate an error afterward.
I can't explain why some uninterpreted code can generate an error, and I can't understand why this particular one can have any consequences.

I guess this is in the end just because I don't really get what `globals()` is doing.

Does anyone have an explanation, or good documentation talking about this?

Comment: Why does your print statement differ in the same function? Copy paste error?

Comment: `foo()` contains an assignment to `x`, so `x` is assumed to be a local variable.

Comment: This is nothing to do with globals. You have an assignment to x in foo, so it's a *local* variable, irrespective of whether the assignment is reachable.

Comment: Cristal clear, thanks a lot for the answer!